# IEnumerable<ViewModel> vs. IEnumerable<Model> in another Viewmodel (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#

For example I have 2 models: Customer and Order. The relationship is one to many.

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set}
  public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public int CustomerId {get;set}
  public Customer Customer {get;set
}
```

I want to pass data from the View to the database.

Do I have to create a ViewModel for each Model? In this case CustomerViewModel would have a property of IEnumerable of type OrderViewModel.

Or do I have to create just one ViewModel. In this case CustomerViewModel would have a property of IEnumerable of type Order.

I am a little bit confused what approach should be taken. What is the best practice?

For example:

CustomerViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> Orders {get;set;}
}
```

OrderViewModel:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
   public int Id
}
```

Or do I have to create just a CustomerViewModel like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Order> Orders {get;set;}
```

Comment: What makes your ViewModel a real one? Have you read about MVVM? Do You use Entity Framework? Pls make yourself a little clearer

Comment: I'm new to C# and I'm trying to understand the best approaches and practices. I use Entity Framework and would like to have a View -> ViewModel -> Model -> Controller ->  Service layer -> Entity framework -> Database.

Comment: You can use ViewModel for collecting data from the View & can save those data to DB. But how you should create the ViewModel depends on, how you collect data. Share your code from view, then it will be easy to give you the proper answer.

Comment: In the view for example I will have a form with two inputs: CustomerName and OrderId. Both would be filled out by the user. In that view I am going to pass the CustomerViewModel. The question is, do I need a property in the CustomerViewModel of type IEnumerable<Order> or type IEnumerable<OrderViewModel>. I suppose both would work, but what is the best practice?